# Need to add filter with more than one word in view filter criteria Drupal7

Tags: 7, views, search

I need to add one filter that can take more than one word for searching.
Right now i selected "contains" option in Operator for filter criteria.
ie i need search string like this:
title=word1 or word2…

So in this case what should be my search url:
search-page?title=word1 word2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want.

[image]